# How to create native android app on MobileFirst

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed the plug in of MobileFirst in my eclipse. I have created the native android project. 
But where to create the activities and xml layouts.
Cant someone help me to create native android application on MobileFirst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MobileFirst Studio (v5.x-v7.1) you do not create **native projects**, rather you create the **native API/SDK** that you need to then **put in your native project**.

In the studio, you:

1. Generate the native API. You then copy the produced artifacts into your project
2. Deploy it to the server, so the server will know the app "exists".

You need to create your own native project in Android Studio, and follow the instructions on adding the SDK to your project. Review this tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/configuring-a-native-android-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/

Comment: I didn't get you. Do i need to follow these four steps.

Agenda
    1) Adding the MobileFirst Native SDK to an application
    2) Deploying the server-side entity to MobileFirst Server
    3) Inside a native application containing the MobileFirst Native SDK
    4) Tutorials to follow next

Comment: What did you not understand? you **do not create a native app** using IBM MobileFirst. IBM MobileFirst only **supplies you with the SDK**. You need to **create the native app on your own** and add to it the SDK. Follow the instructions in the tutorial I have linked you to.

Comment: Do i need to install CLI also?

Comment: You can use either CLI or Studio.

Comment: I read the link which you mentioned but it very confusing, what things needed to create native app.
I have eclipse installed with mobileFirst  plug in, and have created android project in android studio.
Now in order to make my application native mobileFirst app what should I need to do?

Comment: Go and learn android programming...

Comment: You need Android Studio IDE to create android native apps.

Comment: I have created the application in android studio. But my client requirement is he wants native android application which is built in MoibleFirst.

Comment: What you keep failing to understand is that IBM MobileFirst **only supplies you with an SDK that you put into your own native app**. Do you understand now? MobileFirst is an SDK to talk with the MobileFirst Server. You don't create your app using MobileFirst.

Comment: That's what I want to know. I am very new to this mobileFirst. 
How to put mobileFirst SDK in project developed in android studio

Comment: Read the tutorial.